# Using diff() in R with NA and negative numbers

Tags: r, difference

I have a R DataFrame df with the following content:

```
Serial N         year         current
   B              10            14
   B              10            16
   B              11            10
   B              11            NA
   B              11            15
   C              12            11
   C              12             9
   C              12            13
   C              12            17
   .              .              .
```

I would like to find the difference between the each consecutive pair of current of the same serial N. This is code I wrote.But I am getting some strange results

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,mydiff:=diff(df$current),by=Serial N]   
print(length(df$current))
```

I get the following as outuput for that column is quite strange, I get this:

```
2 6  NA NA NA 2 6  NA NA NA
```

What I would like to have actually is :

```
Serial N         year         current      mydiff
   B              10            14         
   B              10            16         16-14=2
   B              11            10         10-16=-4
   B              11            NA            NA
   B              11            15         15-10=5
   C              12            11
   C              12             9         9-11=-2    
   C              12           -13        -13-9=-22
   C              12            17         17-(-13)=30
   .              .              .
```

Is diff the right thing to do that? if not, how can tackle this (especially without using loops)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work for you.  You can bring values forward with na.locf from the zoo package.  The ifelse condition only populates my.diff if current is not NA.

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
df <- read.table(textConnection("
                         'Serial N'         year         current
                            B              10            14
                            B              10            16
                            B              11            10
                            B              11            NA
                            B              11            15
                            C              12            11
                            C              12             9
                            C              12            -13
                            C              12            17"),header=TRUE)

setDT(df)
setkey(df,Serial.N)
df[,my.diff := ifelse(!is.na(current), c(" ",diff(na.locf(current))), NA),by=Serial.N]  


#        Serial.N year current my.diff
# 1:        B   10      14        
# 2:        B   10      16       2
# 3:        B   11      10      -6
# 4:        B   11      NA      NA
# 5:        B   11      15       5
# 6:        C   12      11        
# 7:        C   12       9      -2
# 8:        C   12     -13     -22
# 9:        C   12      17      30
```